# Git - View history for a specific submodule with corresponding hashes

Tags: git, git-submodules

I ran `git submodule update --remote` on my repository and then pushed to master after checking regression tests. However, my tests did not have 100% coverage and something slipped through. I want to revert back to the previous hash in one of my submodules before the remote update.

Two questions:

- How do acquire the previous hash of the submodule before
  the remote update?
- Once I get that hash how do I properly reset the submodule to that hash?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To look at the previously checked out submodule hashes:

```
git log --patch master -- path/to/submodule
```

Use this to figure out what commit updated the checked-out submodule, and then you can roll back the checked-out submodule like so:

```
git checkout <commit>^ -- path/to/submodule && git submodule update -- path/to/submodule
```

Which will leave your repo with the old submodule checked out, and said change in the staging area.